# How to get records from 3 belongsToMany

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table structured like this.

```
user_company
  user_id
  company_id

user_dispensary
  user_id
  dispensary_id

user_group
  user_id
  group_id

// User.php
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class,'user_group','user_id');
}

public function dispensary()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Dispensary::class, 'user_dispensary', 'user_id');
}

public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'user_company', 'user_id');
}

// Company.php
public function dispensary()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Dispensary::class);
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_company', 'company_id');
}

// Dispensary.php
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_dispensary', 'dispensary_id');
}
```

I have tried this to get the users of the company where the user is.

```
\Auth::user()->company()->first()->users
```

But what I want is to get the records of all the users in a company where the current loggedin user is along with their groups and the users of the dispensaries where those dispensaries belongs to the company where the current user is.

Comment: does `\Auth::user()->company` work? if yes, add here your company model, maybe that's where you have to check

Comment: yes it does. it returns which company the user belongs. I don't get the 'add here your company model'. what do you mean?