# Laravel Relationship - Get all teams belongs to organization for user

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship, laravel-10

I have following models in Laravel:

- User Model
- Team Model
- Company Model

And DB tables:

```
users
- id

company
- id

teams
- id
- company_id  (team can only belong to one company)

// pivot tables
company_user
- user_id
- company_id

team_user
- team_id
- user_id
```

I'm trying to create relationship on User Model that will get Company With teams that only belongs to that user. I can make it with joins, but I would like to have a relationship. I have tried different packages, but still can't figure it out. It's just sad 8 hours.

Comment: Users can have more than one company?

Comment: If i undestand well, that will be enough. Can you test it?
`public function companiesWithTeams()
    {
        return Company::whereHas('teams', function ($query) {
            $query->whereIn('id', $this->teams()->pluck('id'));
        })->get();
    }`

Comment: @ManuelGuzman Yes, why not.

Comment: @LucasPace thank you. I know you can query this way, it's not an issue. The issue is that I need Relationship back, that's the issues I can't solve. I even tried to add WITH  after the standard relationship in the model, but can't figure out how to pass 'user_id' or whatever from the relation.

Comment: You need return companies and the user list of each them? What relation you need back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your scenario, a user can work for multiple companies, and each company can have multiple teams. You want to quickly see which companies a user belongs to, along with the specific teams they're part of within those companies.

For this, you can create a function in the User model called "**`companyWithTeams`**".

This function will recognize that a user can be linked to many companies, and it uses a pivot table called "**`CompanyUser`**" to keep track of these relations. It also gets `user_ids` from "**`CompanyUser`**" to link the right teams. This function will fetch the companies a user belongs to but also immediately fetch the teams within those companies.

**User Model:**

```
public function companyWithTeams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class)
                ->using(CompanyUser::class)
                ->withPivot('user_id')
                ->with(['teams' => function ($query) {
                    // Filter teams to those that the user belongs to
                    $query->whereHas('users', function ($query) {
                        $query->where('user_id', $this->id);
                    });
                }]);
}
```

**Company Model:**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
                ->using(CompanyUser::class)
                ->withPivot('user_id');
}

public function teams()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Team::class);
}
```

**Team Model:**

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
                ->using(TeamUser::class)
                ->withPivot('user_id');
}
```

**In your controller, you can access:**

```
$user = User::find(1);
$companyWithTeams = $user->companyWithTeams;

$companyName = $companyWithTeams->name;

foreach ($companyWithTeams->teams as $team) {
    echo $team->name;
}
```

---

**Here is a similar question:**

[How to get records from 3 belongsToMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52142137/how-to-get-records-from-3-belongstomany)

Comment: I can't thank you enough @talha2k. I was so close, I read somewhere that you can't use $this in the relationship, so I was confused how to do it. Spend so much time, but it's actually pretty straightforward.